# How to find this limit in statistics?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, probability-distributions

$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \left( \frac{n}{2}\cdot\left(y - t + n^{-1}\right)\right)
$$

where $y$ is a random variable and $t$ is a real number.

Its result seems to be infinity but my book said that it is $\frac{1}{2}$.

Thank you for helping me.

Comment: If the limit is indeed as Avraham edited for you, the answer is really infinity...

Comment: SON TO, please check that I properly transcribed your notes. The $(y-t)$ is inside the parenthesis. So unless $y=t$, we have a non-zero value multiplied by $n$ as it is going off to infinity.

Comment: Yes, my bad, I misread. Let me delete my post.

Comment: I agree with Avraham. @SONTO see my answer below.

Comment: Wow! I understand now. I thank you all for helping me. It means much to me!!! And the edit version is perfect...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on the answer above (and in the comments) and make it a bit clearer, hopefully:
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \left( \frac{n}{2}\cdot\left(y - t + n^{-1}\right)\right)\\
\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(\frac{n\cdot\left(y - t + n^{-1}\right)}{2}\right)\\
\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(\frac{\left(ny - nt + 1\right)}{2}\right)\\
\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(\frac{n\left(y - t \right) + 1}{2}\right)\\
$$ 
The numerator is going to $\pm\infty$ depending on the magnitudes of $y$ and $t$ and the denominator is a constant, so the limit as written above diverges, **unless** $y=t$ in which case the limit is $\frac{1}{2}$ as the $n$ term is identically $0$ for all $n$.

Answer (score 1):

Take the limit:

```
lim_{n->infinity} 1/2 n (1/n-t+y)
```

Factor out constants:

```
  1/2 (lim_(n->infinity) n (1/n-t+y))
```

The limit of n (1/n-t+y) as n approaches infinity is (-t+y) infinity:

Answer: (-t+y) infinity

Now, y is a random variable for some event, so it can be at most 1, and t can be any number, big as we want. therefore we don't have any bounded limit and it goes to infinity

Comment: As written, $y$ is a value, not a probability, and so can be a real-valued random variable (for example, $y \sim \mathit(N)(100, 100000))$ thus taking any value $t$ can, in theory.